# React Component - Plotly Chart Creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

I have a ReactJS website. Have to create a page with a Plot.ly chart creator same as https://plot.ly/create/ (basically, only left side of the editor)

Are there any React component that has the similar feature? Could be not a react component.

Something like `<PlotlyEditor ...../>`

P.S. New to the ReactJS world. Couldn't find any on the google. Hoping, experienced React devs will show some hidden gems and advices ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually do have a project which does exactly this: it exposes `<PlotlyEditor />` over at https://github.com/plotly/react-chart-editor

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I don know any 'magic' React component that do ALL what ploty does...I can give you some solutions for some pieces of the problem:

- Graph Library: http://www.reactd3.org/
- Table Library with a lot of features built in: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid